# Is it possible to check in a file or add a file to an SVN repository without an SVN client?

Tags: svn, upload, client, commit, addition

Is it possible to check in a file or add a file to an SVN repository without an SVN client?  Using a browser, I was able to access the files on an SVN server using Apache.  If I don't have an SVN client on a certain computer, can I add the file (and commit it), such as by the browser's "Upload File" function?  Being able to do so could be handy.

Comment: Anything capable of doing so would be an SVN client. Can you tell us why you can't download a client? (http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache + SVN  uses WebDav to access the repository.  The reason you can browse the repository with a standard web browser is because the standard GET commands get a listing (and the file) of the svn file.  To add and commit to a repository, it uses different commands that are not standard HTTP talk.

The bottom line is that you need an SVN-aware browser to be able to do what your asking.  I believe theres actually a firefox plugin that adds this support ("subversion menu", or something of that sort), but i have never used it and thus can't vouch for its usefulness.

**Update:**Its actually called "TortoiseSVN Menu", and ties into a TortoiseSVN installation already on your computer, so it doesn't work as i thought.

**Update 2:** If you're interested in the WebDav commands, I found the use of them detailed in a document at http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-protocol

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Autoversioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.webdav.autoversioning.html), with this approach users can work with the repository as if it were a regular network share. Changes will be automatically committed. Naturally you lose commit comments and any ability to form meaningful commits of more than one file at a time.

I've never actually used the feature. I don't think I'd like it.